# R - Time Series ggplot Missing column

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, transpose

I am working to develop a time series plot in R. However, I can not seem to be able to access the columns in my data frame. The error message is **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Dates' not found**.

Below includes my script and the brief table. Any help is much appreciated.

```
# Transpose USA to get dates
t_USA_G_1 <- as.data.frame(t(USA_G_1_date))

#Rename column headers
colnames(t_USA_G_1)[0] = "Dates"
colnames(t_USA_G_1)[1] = "USA_Net_Enrollment"
t_USA_G_1

#Time series plot
t_USA_G_1%>%
  ggplot(aes(Dates, USA_Net_Enrollment)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

------Output-----

```
     USA_Net_Enrollment
1999           96.56902
2000           96.69755
2001           96.28022
2002           94.99747
2003           94.74116
2004           93.37412
2005           93.68804
2006           94.81912
2007           95.86296
2008           96.26724
2009           94.81539
2010           93.62400
2011           92.91374
2012           93.16648
2013           92.77709
2014           93.09830
2015           93.75419
```

Comment: Change the `ggplot` call to refer to `Dates` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for the catch. However, the error still occurs.

Comment: Try `colnames(t_USA_G_1)[1] = "Dates"` - in R indexing starts at 1, not 0

Comment: That was used as seen above, for colnames(t_USA_G_1)[0] = "Dates"
colnames(t_USA_G_1)[1] = "USA_Net_Enrollment"

Comment: I think you missed @MRau's point: `colnames(t_USA_G_1)[0]` will get you an empty vector, because in R there won't be anything at index 0, so you won't actually be changing the name of a column to "Dates". This is one way R differs from many other languages which start at 0

Comment: Understood camille. My apologies MRua.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using row.names.

```
t_USA_G_1%>%
  ggplot(aes(row.names(t_USA_G_1), USA_Net_Enrollment)) + 
  geom_point(color="blue")+
  labs(x="Dates", y="USA Net Enrollment")
```